# NullPointerException when inflating a PopupWindow

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, popupwindow

I'm trying to inflate a PopupWindow from a button that sits within list items (from a custom list adapter) but am getting NullPointerExceptions in multiple places.

Here's the onClick for the button where I'm trying to make the PopupWindow happen:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PopupWindow pw = null;
if (scores[0] == null) {
    pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_table_row, null, false), 100, 100, true);
    TextView tag = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag);
    tag.setText("error!");
} else {
    int x = tags.length;
    int y = 5; 
    int z = Math.min(x, y); 

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_table_row, null, false), 100, 100, true);                        
            TextView tag = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag);
            tag.setText(tags[i]);
            int tag1score = Double.parseDouble(scores[i]);
            TextView score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tagscore);
            score.setText(Integer.toString(tag1score));
    }
}
pw.showAtLocation(v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_content), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm getting the NullPointerException at `tag.setText(tags[i]);`.  If I comment that and just try to do scores, I get a NullPointerException at `score.setText(Integer.toString(tag1score));`.  Both tags[] and scores[] are initialized and filled before the onClick, and I've tested to ensure that the results in both are Strings and NOT null.

Any thoughts as to why this NPE is happening?

Comment: What happens if you just do `TextView tag = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tag);` without using `v`?

Comment: I get the error "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: Basically you need to get the right context. Try to get the context of window/activity where your TextView is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right thing wherein to look for the view.  You are inflating into pw, but you are looking in v for your views. I think this might work better;

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = null;
    PopupWindow pw = null;
    if (scores[0] == null) {
        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_table_row, null, false);  
        pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, 100, 100, true);                      

        TextView tag = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag);
        tag.setText("error!");
    } else {
        int x = tags.length;
        int y = 5; 
        int z = Math.min(x, y); 

        for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
            popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_table_row, null, false);  
            pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, 100, 100, true);                      
            TextView tag = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tag);
            tag.setText(tags[i]);
            int tag1score = Double.parseDouble(scores[i]);
            TextView score = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tagscore);
            score.setText(Integer.toString(tag1score));
        }
    }
    pw.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

it keeps track of the view you have inflated into, so you can search it for your elements.

Comment: Thank you.  What you're saying makes sense to me. But... popupwindow doesn't have a findViewById method (or seemingly anything like it).  Thoughts?

Comment: see changes in answer.  You should track the view you've inflated into.

Comment: `TextView score = (TextView) pw.findViewById(R.id.tagscore);` should be `TextView score = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tagscore);`.

Comment: @user2163853 Also, `pw.showAtLocation(v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_content), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);` will need to be changed to `pw.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);`. You can use another view as an anchor, but since you are using `Gravity.CENTER` and coordinates (0,0), it would hardly matter. `popupView` will do.

Comment: Edited again-- see above.